# android webrtc cannot connected between LTE hostspot and wifi using coturn server

Tags: android, webrtc, coturn

I'm developing android webRTC with [coturn](https://github.com/coturn/coturn/wiki/turnserver) trun server. There is a problem in connection.

**Case 1. no problem**

Offer(LTE hotspot wifi connected device) -> <- Answer(WIFI connected device)

=> Always connected well

**Case 2. problem in connection**

Offer(WIFI connected device) -> <- Answer(LTE hotspot wifi connected device)

=> Always iceConnectionState failed.

my coturn server running command is

```
turnserver -X <publicip>/<privateip> --no-tls --no-dtls --min-port 50000 --max-port 60000 -r my.domain --no-auth --syslog -l stdout --relay-ip <privateip>
```

turn server is running aws amazon linux ec2 instance.

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a problem. when use --no-auth option, TCP connection always can't be made.
remove --no-auth option, and use authentication method.

I used lt-cred-mech option. and make user with turnadmin command.